# TypeError : file.getName is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror, drive

This is my first time on Stack overflow so please excuse if any information is missing. Here is my problem :

I am writing a Google Apps Script code that print for a given folder (fatherFolder), the files and folders that can be found in the fatherFolder. When going thru the folders it works, but when going thru the files it returns the error "file.getName is not a function".

I tried other file method such as getDownloadUrl or getId and the same error occurs.
When I get a file this way for example : var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id), the method getName() works.

Here is the code :

```
function test4() {
  var id = "folderIdOfMyDrive";
  //When this will be working, Id will be an argument and not given in the code
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  var foldersIterator = folder.getFolders();
  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  
  //This works quite properly
  while (foldersIterator.hasNext()) {
    var sonsFolder = foldersIterator.next();
    var name = sonsFolder.getName();
    Logger.log(name);
  }
  
  //And this don't
  while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesIterator.next;
    var name = file.getName();
    Logger.log(name);
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me if I did something wrong ?

Comment: How about modifying from `var file = filesIterator.next;` to `var file = filesIterator.next();`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next()) By adding `()` to `next`, the method can be run.

Comment: Try using the autocomplete feature (CTRL+SPACE) when you write code, it will prevent this kind of error